# JavaFX creating series for linechart: null

Tags: javafx, null, series, linechart

I am creating a new window controller in which I process data to be put into a linechart.

Though in the end the new window shows an empty LineChart. When I debug the line in which the series is put into the Linechart, the IDE states "series[null]".

So what am I missing?

Class of the new window:

public class ChartWindow {

```
Map<Job, List<LoadTestResultStatus>> lTRSMapOfJobs;

final LineChart lineChartMain;

Job originJob;

XYChart.Series series;

boolean lTRSfilled=false;

ObjectHub objectHub;

public ChartWindow(Job job, ObjectHub objectHub) {
    this.objectHub = objectHub;

    series = new XYChart.Series();

    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

    xAxis.setLabel("Time");
    yAxis.setLabel("Time");

    lineChartMain = new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);

    lTRSMapOfJobs = new HashMap<>();

    originJob = job;

    lTRSMapOfJobs.put(job, objectHub.getDbManagement().getLTRSListOfJobFromDB(job));

    fillLineChart();

}

public void fillLineChart() {

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            objectHub.getGuiReporter().statusStart(0);
            objectHub.getGuiReporter().progressbarAddAmountOfStep(lTRSMapOfJobs.get(originJob).size());

        }
    });

    for (LoadTestResultStatus l : lTRSMapOfJobs.get(originJob)) {
        objectHub.getExecutor().submit(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                XYChart.Data xyChart = new XYChart.Data(l.getTs(), l.getLt());
                try {
                    addToSeries(xyChart);
                    objectHub.getGuiReporter().progressbarAddStep();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    //TODO heavy CPU load:(
    while(!lTRSfilled){
        if(ObjectHub.getGuiReporter().progressBarDifference()==0){
            lTRSfilled = true;
        }
    }
    lineChartMain.getData().addAll(series);
}


void addToSeries(XYChart.Data xyChart) {
    synchronized (this) {
        series.getData().add(xyChart);
    }
}

public Map<Job, List<LoadTestResultStatus>> getlTRSMapOfJobs() {
    return lTRSMapOfJobs;
}

public void setlTRSMapOfJobs(Map<Job, List<LoadTestResultStatus>> lTRSMapOfJobs) {
    this.lTRSMapOfJobs = lTRSMapOfJobs;
}

public LineChart getLineChartMain() {
    return lineChartMain;
}
```

}

MainController method who processes the new window:

```
 public void showLineChartForJob() {
    progressBarLabel.setText("Preparing Linechart calculation...");

   ChartWindow object to request executorservices

    Thread createChartWindow = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            int jobId = Integer.parseInt(visualizeTabIdInputTextField.getText());

            Job lineChartJob = new Job(objectHub);

            for (Job j : objectHub.getLtResultManagement().getjobSet()) {
                if (j.getNumber() == jobId) {
                    lineChartJob = j;
                    break;
                }
            }

            chartWindowList.add(new ChartWindow(lineChartJob, objectHub));

            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/ChartWindow.fxml"));
                    fxmlLoader.setController(chartWindowList.get(0));
                    StackPane secondaryLayout = new StackPane();
                    try {
                        secondaryLayout.getChildren().setAll(Collections.singleton(fxmlLoader.load()));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Scene secondScene = new Scene(secondaryLayout, 1200, 1600);

                    Stage newWindow = new Stage();
                    newWindow.setTitle("Second Stage");
                    newWindow.setScene(secondScene);


                    newWindow.setX(50);
                    newWindow.setY(50);

                    newWindow.show();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    createChartWindow.setName("createChartWindowThread");
    createChartWindow.start();
}
```

Capture from debug taken at the last line of the First Controller:
[image]

Regards

Comment: `Series#toString()` returns `"Series[" + getName() + "]"`. If no name is set you end up with `Series[null]`. Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: Not exactely, out of dispair I was assume that a critical field in the series was perhaps not initiliazed.
This this is a very helpful comment too. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, case closed:

Failure was to not adress the scene to the linechart:

```
 Scene secondScene = new Scene(secondaryLayout, 1200, 1600);
```

Fixed by obtaining the chart from the controller:

```
Scene secondScene = new Scene(chartWindowList.get(0).lineChartMain, 1200, 1600);
```